# How to configure UFT 15.02 with a JDK 11 Java app

Tags: hp-uft

I'm using UFT 15.02.  According to the page:
https://admhelp.microfocus.com/documents/uft/PAM/UFT_15.X_PAM.html#UFT%20GUI%20Testing%20Java%20Add-in

UFT 15.02 is compatible with the Open JDK 11.

When our application is built with JDK 8, UFT works fine and can spy objects and get their details.  When our application is built with Open JDK 11, UFT can't spy any objects or their details, just see's the application as a generic window.  I have the Java Addin selected.

Here is what happens:
[image]

When Open Web Start runs and launches the JDK 11 application the console displays a message showing UFT support for Java 1.8.  I haven't found a setting or anything that affects this.
[image]

Any ideas?